# finding max value among two table without using max function in relational algebra

Tags: database, max, relational-algebra

Suppose I have two tables `A{int m}` and `B{int m}` and I have to find maximum **m** among two tables using relational algebra but I cannot use max function.How can I do it?I think using join we can do it but i am not sure if my guess is correct or not.

**Note:** this is an interview question.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, I'm puzzled why the question involves two tables. For the question as asked, I would just UNION the two (as StilesCrisis has done), then solve for a single table.

So: how to find the maximum m in a table using only NatJOIN? This is a simplified version of finding the top node on a table that holds a hierarchy (think assembly/component explosions or org charts).

The key idea is that we need to 'copy' the table into something with a different attribute name so that we can compare the tuples pair-wise. (And this will therefore use the degenerate form of NatJOIN aka cross-product). See example here [How can I find MAX with relational algebra?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493691/how-can-i-find-max-with-relational-algebra?rq=1)

```
A NOT MATCHING
((A x (A RENAME m AS mm)) WHERE m < mm)
```

The subtrahend is all tuples with m less than some other tuples. The anti-join is all the tuples except those -- ie the MAX. (Using NOT MATCHING I think is both more understandable than MINUS, and doesn't need the relations to be UNION-compatible. It's roughly equivalent to SQL NOT EXISTS).)

[I've used Tutorial D syntax, to avoid mucking about with greek letters.]

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT M FROM (SELECT M FROM A UNION SELECT M FROM B) ORDER BY M DESC LIMIT 1
```

This doesn't use `MAX`, just plain vanilla SQL.

Comment: I think you did not read my question completely.I have to use relational algebra and not sql