# Relational algebra aggregate function

Tags: database, relational-algebra

I have following employee schema:

employee (id, name, address, age)

To find out the name of oldest employee, I know the SQL which looks like:

```
select name from employee,
(select max(age) max_age from employee) e2
where age=max_age
```

but I am not sure how to do that in relational algebra. Once again, text books have not mentioned how to do such things.

My probable solution looks like follows:

π<sub>name</sub> (σ<sub>age=max_age</sub>( employee × 
ρ<sub>max_age/age</sub>(ℱ<sub>max(age)</sub>(employee)) ))

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Aggregate Relational Algebra (Maximum)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952451/aggregate-relational-algebra-maximum)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Query using aggregation and/or groups in relational algebra - count, max, min, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15660545/3404097)

Comment: There are many RAs (relational algebras). They differ in operators & even what a relation is. Give operator definitions & your reference for yours. Eg textbook name, edition & page. Nested algebra calls form a programming language. So give as much of a [mre] as you can. But--Google 'run relational algebra online'. Re "is this right": [ask] [Help] PS [Re relational querying.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24425914/3404097) [More.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55671890/3404097) PS Changing SQL subquery use to joins is a faq. PS What exactly is your 1 (specific researched non-duplicate) question?

Answer (score 1):

Your "probable solution" is not wrong, but is too complex.

Note that the filter (σ <sub>age = max_age</sub>) is a test for equality, and that max_age is a rename of age. You can avoid the rename and the sigma by putting a nat join instead of the cross-product:

πname ( employee ⋈ (ℱmax(age)(employee)) )

I'm not surprised you can't find this in textbooks:

1) they don't teach the full power of natural join.

2) they don't cover aggregate functions very thoroughly.

And that's because of weaknesses in SQL compared with RA (IMO):

1) natural join is a relatively recent innovation in SQL (not well supported).

2) SQL's implementation of aggregates is ghastly.

BTW, you can avoid the max aggregate altogether, with a bit more work, see [finding max value among two table without using max function in relational algebra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21847894/finding-max-value-among-two-table-without-using-max-function-in-relational-algeb/21974323#21974323)