# How to retrieve all grand parents at once

Tags: sql, sqlite, foreign-keys, inner-join

I have two simple tables in SQLITE3 (family bonds):

"persons" (id, fname, lname)
"relationships" (parent/child)

I would like to get each grand children along with all their grand parents (from 1 to 4 of them depending on the grand child) so that 1 row result =

```
Distinct Grand child, Grand parent 1, Grand parent 2, Grand parent 3, Grand parent 4
```

Thanks to Caius Jard, I've been able to get each child  and its grand parents in another star overflow question. However, so far I have:
1 line = Grand child, 1 grand parent (so it needs up to 4 lines to get all grand parents of a child).

```
SELECT c.fname, c.lname, gp.fname, gp.lname  
FROM relations p_c
INNER JOIN relationships gp_p ON gp_p.child = p_c.parent 
INNER JOIN persons gp ON gp.id = gp_p.parent 
INNER JOIN persons c ON c.id = p_c.child
ORDER BY c.id;
```

How could I edit this so that I get each grand child along with all the grand parents in one single row result?

If possible only using SELECT (+ count/distinct), WHERE (+in/exists), INNER/LEFT JOIN, GROUP BY (+having), ORDER BY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there are four grandparents, you can enumerate them and aggregate:

```
SELECT fname, lname,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 THEN grandparent_name END) as grandparent_1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 2 THEN grandparent_name END) as grandparent_2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 3 THEN grandparent_name END) as grandparent_3,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 4 THEN grandparent_name END) as grandparent_4
FROM (SELECT c.id, c.fname, c.lname,
             gp.fname || ' ' || gp.lname as grandparent_name,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.id ORDER BY gp.fname, gp.lanme) as seqnum 
      FROM relations p_c JOIN
           relationships gp_p
           ON gp_p.child = p_c.parent JOIN
           persons gp
           ON gp.id = gp_p.parent 
           persons c
           ON c.id = p_c.child
     ) cgp
GROUP BY fname, lname, id;
```

Comment: Thanks. This solution works beautifully. But the clauses and functions are beyond my boundaries (partition, over, row_number) as I follow the chapter of a textbook that doesn't use those. Still interesting to learn from your query though. Thank you !
I accepted it because although I will use the answer from forpas, yours is the closest to the question.

Comment: It's sad because I specifically asked forpas if it's alright if I accept your answer. So I haven't been rude or anything. If anything, Ihave been considerate. Anyway, that's the way it is apparently. Just want to say that I thank everyone who helped. But the nature of the website is to only be able to accept one answer even though many can be acceptable. I fail to see how I am responsible for that feature. I can only be responsible for me being considerate and polite and I truly believe I have been. Let's hope I've been downvoted for something else, which is possible.

Answer (score 2):

We can turn rows into columns by a technique known as conditional aggregation:

Suppose you have a result set:

```
x, y
1, hello
2, goodbye
```

If you wrote this:

```
SELECT x, 
  CASE WHEN x = 1 THEN y END as x1, 
  CASE WHEN x = 2 THEN y END as x2
FROM ...
```

You would get this:

```
x, x1, x2
1, hello, NULL
2, NULL, goodbye
```

There is only one value in a column, the rest are null. If you then use e.g. MAX, which discards nulls:

```
SELECT
  MAX(CASE WHEN x = 1 THEN y END) as x1, 
  MAX(CASE WHEN x = 2 THEN y END) as x2
FROM ...
```

You would get

```
x1, x2
hello, goodbye
```

We've had to drop the x, because we can't put it in there otherwise we'd have to group it, which would prevent rows collapsing down

---

Now to your query, we probably have to add other info in because we need something to CASE WHEN on. You don't indicate that we can arbitrarily throw a row number in there. Hopefully `persons` contains a gender indicator because 4 grandparents are the result of two males and two females arising from one male and one female (so we have MM - father's father, MF - father's mother, FM and FF etc)

```
SELECT ...  
FROM relations p_c
INNER JOIN relationships gp_p ON gp_p.child = p_c.parent 
INNER JOIN persons gp ON gp.id = gp_p.parent 
INNER JOIN persons p ON p.id = p_c.parent 
INNER JOIN persons c ON c.id = p_c.child
```

We can now query the gender of each level of family tree:

```
SELECT c.name as child,
  CASE WHEN gp.gender = 'm' AND p.gender = 'm' THEN gp.name END AS fathersfather,
  CASE WHEN gp.gender = 'm' AND p.gender = 'f' THEN gp.name END AS fathersmother,
  CASE WHEN gp.gender = 'f' AND p.gender = 'm' THEN gp.name END AS mothersfather,
  CASE WHEN gp.gender = 'f' AND p.gender = 'f' THEN gp.name END AS mothersmother
FROM relations p_c
INNER JOIN relationships gp_p ON gp_p.child = p_c.parent 
INNER JOIN persons gp ON gp.id = gp_p.parent 
INNER JOIN persons p ON p.id = p_c.parent 
INNER JOIN persons c ON c.id = p_c.child
```

This will give the child and then a diagonal array of the grandparent names. You can squish it to a row per child with:

```
SELECT c.name as child,
  MAX(CASE WHEN gp.gender = 'm' AND p.gender = 'm' THEN gp.name END) AS fathersfather,
  MAX(CASE WHEN gp.gender = 'm' AND p.gender = 'f' THEN gp.name END) AS fathersmother,
  MAX(CASE WHEN gp.gender = 'f' AND p.gender = 'm' THEN gp.name END) AS mothersfather,
  MAX(CASE WHEN gp.gender = 'f' AND p.gender = 'f' THEN gp.name END) AS mothersmother
FROM relations p_c
INNER JOIN relationships gp_p ON gp_p.child = p_c.parent 
INNER JOIN persons gp ON gp.id = gp_p.parent 
INNER JOIN persons p ON p.id = p_c.parent 
INNER JOIN persons c ON c.id = p_c.child
GROUP BY c.name
```

Comment: Thank you very much. No the database doesn't include a gender distinction. So your post is very very educative and I really thank you for that because I learn a lot. But it doesn't solve my problem. Can I PM you at some point to explain the context I have to solve this in ? Or don't you want to be bothered (which would be totally understandable) ?

Comment: You just need something to discriminate the rows. It doesn't help that you haven't said what data you do have. If there is nothing to discriminate you will have to introduce a fake discriminator with eg `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY c.name ORDER BY c.name)` to introduce an incrementing counter that is 1 they 4 and resets per child; then you can `CASE WHEN 1 THEN ...`. A fake discriminator such as this won't guarantee anything about the grandparent such as whether they're the father's father etc (which is what the gender gives you). Take a look at what data you have that you can use

Comment: You should also consider grouping by the child ID rather than name if you have two children named the same

Comment: I understand what you say but what I don't get is that I can  display 4 rows for the same grand child with its 4 grand parents (you helped me for that) so there must be something there that could just group those in one single line, like joining the result to itself at the end or something? Anyway, your help was already more than I wished for. Super thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of 4 columns for the grand parents, I would suggest to use `GROUP_CONCAT()` and get 1 column with all the grandparents:

```
SELECT p.fname, p.lname,
       GROUP_CONCAT(gp.fname || ' ' || gp.lname, '|')
FROM persons p
INNER JOIN relationships r1 ON r1.child = p.id
INNER JOIN relationships r2 ON r2.child = r1.parent
INNER JOIN persons gp ON r2.parent = gp.id
GROUP BY p.id
```

The code is by far simpler.
Use `LEFT` joins instead of `INNER` joins if you want all the persons returned, even the ones without grandparents.

Comment: Thank you very much. it's elegant. The "Seperator" doesn't work though (sqlite3). I get an error message. And if I get rid of it, the concat column just gives a bunch of zeros, not text, instead of grand parents names.

Comment: @BachirMessaouri you are right. The keyword SEPARATOR should not be there. I edited.

Comment: @BachirMessaouri also if you want `,` as a separator it's even simpler: `GROUP_CONCAT(gp.fname || ' ' || gp.lname)`

Comment: Brillinat. I hope you don't mind: I accepted your answer but the one of Gordon lino is, for other users, the closest to the question (all GP are in columns). I will use your answer though because it uses the clauses I know about. If it feels not right, just tell me and I will accept your answer instead. Thank you very much.

Comment: @BachirMessaouri it's up to you to accept the answer that solves your problem best.