# A basic relational algebra

Tags: database, database-design, relational-algebra

I'm kinda stuck on this relational algebra question, any help would be really appreciated. Many thanks!

> Schema: 
> ***Product (maker, model, type) 
> PC (model, speed, ram, harddrive,
>   screen, price)***
>
> Using **no** aggregate function, list the maker that makes the PC with the
>   fastest processor.

It seems we could draw a solution by using speed = max(speed) aggregate function
easily,

but how can we solve it without aggregate function? I'm kinda confused.

Thanks!

Comment: My confusion is: if you think my last question is unclear and ambiguous. Why you downvoted THIS NEW QUESTION, instead of the last one?

Comment: So, in your viewpoint, people only can ask advanced question/topics on stack-overflow? Here I can't figure out a solution by the link u provided (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24423150/relational-algebra-for-banking-scenario/24425914#24425914) .

Comment: Peter, another of expressing the question is to list makers of models for which no faster model exists.

Comment: Your messages do not reflect paying much attention to what you read. I never said your question was unclear or ambiguous, and I don't know why you think you know I did or didn't downvote either of your questions. I will copy the comment I was referring to here.

Comment: Please give a reference to the version of RA you are supposed to use--there are many. Please read the downvote arrow mouseover text, [ask] & hits from googling 'stackexchange homework'. What is some part of the solution? What do you understand is relevant? What point in a similar textbook example are you stuck at? See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24425914/3404097)--show your work following it until you are stuck. Please clarify by editing your question, not comments. Right now your question is too broad--you're asking for a personalized textbook chapter--read a textbook.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I find MAX with relational algebra?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493691/how-can-i-find-max-with-relational-algebra)