# Finding max value from count without using max

Tags: sql

I have

```
Voters(name,vote, score,time)
```

Where name is the primary key and vote the ID of the person whom the voters voted for.
1 person can vote more than once.

I have to find the name of the person who has voted the most number of times. 
`{Maximum Count(vote)}` without using max command.

Comment: `ORDER BY` and `TOP (1)`/`LIMIT 1`?

Comment: What RDBMS you are using???????

Comment: @Guybrush If your question has been answered, please mark the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can use  `count()`, then try ordering your results by it. In MySQL, your query could look like

```
SELECT name, COUNT(vote) AS total_votes
FROM Voters
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY total_votes DESC
LIMIT 1
```

This would return the person who has voted the most together with his vote count.

Answer (score 1):

You can use concept from relational algebra. `limit 1` does not give good result when more than one user have the same number of votes.

On PostgreSQL:

```
with t as (select name, count(*) c from voters group by name)
SELECT t.* from t
except
SELECT t.* from t JOIN t t2 ON t2.c > t.c
```

[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/bc113/6)

And sample data to prove this works:

```
create table voters (name int,vote int);

insert into voters values (1,1);
insert into voters values (1,1);
insert into voters values (1,1);
insert into voters values (1,1);
insert into voters values (1,1);
insert into voters values (1,1);
insert into voters values (1,1);
insert into voters values (1,1);
insert into voters values (2,1);
insert into voters values (2,1);
insert into voters values (2,1);
insert into voters values (2,1);
insert into voters values (2,1);
insert into voters values (2,1);
insert into voters values (2,1);
insert into voters values (2,1);
insert into voters values (2,1);
insert into voters values (3,1);
insert into voters values (3,1);
insert into voters values (3,1);
insert into voters values (3,1);
insert into voters values (3,1);
insert into voters values (3,1);
insert into voters values (3,1);
insert into voters values (3,1);
insert into voters values (3,1);
insert into voters values (4,1);
insert into voters values (4,1);
insert into voters values (4,1);
insert into voters values (4,1);
insert into voters values (4,1);
insert into voters values (5,1);
insert into voters values (5,1);
insert into voters values (5,1);
insert into voters values (5,1);
```

My solution is based on answer to this question: [How can I find MAX with relational algebra?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493691/how-can-i-find-max-with-relational-algebra)

There is also good explanation of this concept in another answer here [Aggregate Relational Algebra (Maximum)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952451/aggregate-relational-algebra-maximum)

Answer (score 0):

**Try Following**

```
select count(*) from table where vote=(select max(count(*)) from table) group by vote
```

Hope this helps you.