# Relational Algebra - Maximum Value in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, max, algebra, relational

It says everywhere that I suppose to use this in a query
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5333881/5666540

```
SELECT Course.Name FROM Course
    MINUS
SELECT Course.Name FROM Course, Course as Course_1 WHERE Course.Name<Course_1.Name;
```

But my SQL Developer says that there is a mistake in "as", how can I rename that table ... I mean create a temporary one.

Comment: It is neither renaming the table nor creating temporary one. It is called as providing alias to the table name. Syntax does not allow to add as while providing aliases to tables and views in oracle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle syntax does not allow `AS` keyword for normal tables or views. Just remove it.

```
SELECT Course.Name FROM Course
    MINUS
SELECT Course.Name FROM Course, Course Course_1 WHERE Course.Name < Course_1.Name;
```